# Accessing a property declared in an arbitrary superclass

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6

In JavaScript, to access a (non-static) property getter or setter declared in a direct parent class, as we all should know, we can use `super`: e.g. `foo = super.bar` or `super.foo = bar`.

What is the proper way to access an overridden property declared in a super-super-class (or a superclass other than the next parent)?

The best solution I've found so far is using `Relect.get`. It works of course, but it's pretty ugly and looks like a hack. I hope you understand my feelings.

```js
class A {
  get foo() {
    console.log('evaluating A.foo');
    return this.a;
  };
}

class B extends A {
  get foo() {
    console.log('evaluating B.foo');
    return this.b;
  };
}

class C extends B {
  get foo() {
    // Can we get this better?
    return Reflect.get(A.prototype, 'foo', this);
  }
}

const c = new C;
c.a = 'ok';
c.b = 'not ok';
console.log(c.foo);
```

Is there an elegant way to access a property getter/setter declared in an arbitrary superclass?

Comment: Surely needing to do this reveals a significant problem with the class hierarchy?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess so. Was just wondering if I'm overlooking any language features that could be used to do this.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable. There's a lot of hidden gems (and some hidden ... non-gems ...) in the spec. `Reflect.get` is definitely one of the gems, well-spotted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's going to get more elegant/simpler than that. There's no `super.super` or similar in JavaScript.

You could walk the prototype chain instead via `getPrototypeOf` (although doing so isn't *exactly* what `super` does, `super` uses the prototype of the `[[HomeObject]]` of the method), but that's not going to be less complicated or more elegant. :-) More flexible (e.g., not hardcoded to `A`), but not more elegant.